# jQuery .load() stopped working with POST parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So my website has been working fine the last year or so, and parts of it stopped working when I checked it today. This seemed strange to me since I hadn't changed any code.

After some investigation, I think I've pinned the problem down to the jQuery .load() function. I have something like the following in a file called "debug.php":

```
...
<div id="testd"></div>
<p id="mess"></p>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testd").load("../scripts/debug_script.php", {varx: 10}, function() {
            $("#mess").html("inside testd reached")
        });
    });
</script>
```

The file debug_script.php is simply:

```
<?php
$x= $_POST["varx"];
echo "<p>x is $x</p>";
?>
```

With the code above, in the file debug.php, nothing is loaded in the "testd" div, but the message in "mess" shows.

If I delete the `{varx: 10}` argument to `.load()`, the message in "testd" shows up fine (without the actual value of x, obviously).

So it looks like the POST argument in .load is breaking the function somehow. Even when I delete the line `$x= $_POST["varx"];` in the php file being loaded and have just a simple echo, nothing is loaded when the POST argument is included in .load().

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this problem is occurring? Like I said earlier, these .load() calls were working fine on my site until recently, and I have not changed anything at all between when it was working and when it stopped working.

I am linking to jQuery 1.7.2 from Google API (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js), and my host is 000webhost.com. Is it possible that the problem is related to the host? I don't have a local server installed, so all of my testing has been done live, through 000webhost.

Anyway, I would appreciate any ideas people might have. Just let me know if any more info from my end might be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Is your jquery library loaded from your own server or is it being pulled from a public link?

Comment: It's being pulled from a public link: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: The code looks ok (and you said it was working) so maybe the host changed something. Perhaps check the PHP error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending `varx` variable name as a string, like this:

```
$("#testd").load("../scripts/debug_script.php", {'varx': 10}, function() {
    $("#mess").html("inside testd reached")
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!